# Custom AlertDialog with image on top of it

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: How to create Custom AlerDialog like below in android?]

I need to create Customized AlertDialog like above image. Is there any way to achieve this? Your thoughts will be helpful.

Ways tried:
1. I created an Activity with Transparent background and achieved the dialog like above. Is there any other possible good way of achieving it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: i think this qoustion will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643002/android-layer-drawable-loses-information

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom layout with an AlertDialog, but it only affects the content area, so I don't think you can achieve what you want with the AlertDialog.  But, you can create an activity with your layout and use the Dialog theme and probably get the results you need.  Here's an example of how you define the theme in the Android Manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".CustomDialog"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```